# NodeJS & socket.IO emit cutting event payload

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, next.js, socket.io

## Problem

I'm using socket.io as part of a chatbot. It was working fine; however, I have recently started having an issue when emitting events. The payload seems to be getting cut off, resulting in the client disconnecting with a `parse error` error message.

It seems to work fine for very small payloads; however, it fails at a point where there are around 500 characters. I thought it might be related to the payload size; however, it's still relatively small, and I have increased the `maxHttpBufferSize`, and it didn't help.

The payload is around 1884 characters, approximately 3768 bytes (0.0017986297607421875 MB), so should be more than fine.

Edit: I'm using socket.io@4.7.2 socket.io-client@4.7.2. I have tried rolling back to 4.7.1 and 4.7.0 with the same issue.

## Code Example

This is part of a Next.js app, and I'm setting up the socket server via an initial API call. Here is an extract.

```
export default function SocketHandler(req, res) {
    if (res.socket.server.io) {
        res.end(); // Socket already set up
        return;
    }

    const io = new Server(res.socket.server, {
        path: "/api/socket/ping",
        addTrailingSlash: false,
        pingInterval: 50000,
        maxHttpBufferSize: 1e7 //10 * 1024 * 1024 //(10MB)
        
    });

    io.on('connection', (socket) => handleSocketConnection(socket, io));

    corsMiddleware(req, res, () => {
        res.socket.server.io = io;
        res.end();
    });
}
```

The `handleSocketConnection` function is doing some initialisation and setting up event listeners, but at the end, it is emitting the current conversation state. For example.

```
const SOCKET_EVENTS = {
    SERVER_SEND_CONVERSATIONS: 'server_send-conversations', // Emitted when the server sends the current conversations to the client.
};

const conversation = [
            { role: 'assistant', content: ' Hi, how can I help you today?' },
            { role: 'user', content: 'Can you reset my password?' },
            { role: 'assistant', content: 'Sure, I can help with that. To reset your password, please provide me with your username.' },
            { role: 'user', content: 'My username is levi123.' },
            { role: 'assistant', content: 'Thank you, Levi123. I\'ve initiated the password reset process. You will receive an email with further instructions shortly.' },
            { role: 'user', content: 'Great, thanks!' },
            { role: 'assistant', content: 'You\'re welcome! Is there anything else I can assist you with?' },
            { role: 'user', content: 'Yes, I have a question about my account balance.' },
            { role: 'assistant', content: 'Of course, I\'d be happy to help. What\'s your question regarding your account balance?' },
            { role: 'user', content: 'I noticed a discrepancy in my recent transactions.' },
            { role: 'assistant', content: 'I apologize for the inconvenience. Please provide me with the details of the transactions in question, and I\'ll investigate for you.' },
            { role: 'user', content: 'Here are the transaction IDs: 12345 and 67890.' },
            { role: 'assistant', content: 'Thank you for providing the transaction IDs. Let me check those for you. Please hold on for a moment.' },
            { role: 'assistant', content: 'I\'ve reviewed the transactions, and it appears that there was an error. I\'ll work on resolving this issue for you.' },
            { role: 'user', content: 'Thank you for your prompt assistance.' },
            { role: 'assistant', content: 'You\'re welcome! Your issue will be resolved shortly. If you have any more questions, feel free to ask.' },
            { role: 'user', content: 'I appreciate your help. Have a great day!' },
            { role: 'assistant', content: 'You too, Levi. Have a wonderful day!' },
            { role: 'user', content: 'Goodbye!' },
            { role: 'assistant', content: 'Goodbye! If you ever need assistance in the future, don\'t hesitate to reach out.' }
];

socket.emit(SOCKET_EVENTS.SERVER_SEND_CONVERSATIONS, conversation);
```

As mentioned, this is working fine for small arrays, but seems to be failing when they get a little bigger. I end up with an event payload that is cutoff, for example.

```
42["server_send-conversations",[{"role":"assistant","content":" Hi, how can I help you today?"},{"role":"user","content":"Can you reset my password?"},{"role":"assistant","content":"Sure, I can help with that. To reset your password, please provide me with your username."},{"role":"user","content":"My username is levi123."},{"role":"assistant","content":"Thank you, Levi123. I've initiated the password reset process. You will receive an email with further instructions shortly."},{"role":"user","content":"Great, thanks!"},{"role":"assistant","content":"You're welcome! Is there anything else I can assist you with?"},{"role":"user","content":"Yes, I have a question about my account balance."},{"role":"assistant","content":"Of course, I'd be happy to h
```

I don't think the issue is with the client connection, but it looks like this.

```
const socket = io({
   path: `/api/socket/ping`,
   query: { type: 'user', license, token, details },
   reconnection: true,
   reconnectionDelay: 5000,
   reconnectionAttempts: Infinity,
   forceNew: false,
});

...

socket.on(SOCKET_EVENTS.SERVER_SEND_CONVERSATIONS, (context) => {
    console.log('Message Context', context);
    dispatchSocketContext({
        type: socketActionTypes.SET_CONTEXT,
        payload: {
            messages: context
        }
    });
});
```

## Question

I have searched the documentation but am unable to find anything that would explain why the payload is getting cut off. It's always around 500 characters, but not exactly 500 and not always on exactly the same character each time.

Is someone able to suggest what could be causing this issue and point me in the direction of a fix?

Comment: It may be an issue relating to the compression. Turning the compression off solves the issue. For example `socket.compress(false).emit(SOCKET_EVENTS.SERVER_SEND_CONVERSATIONS, [...]);`